# SQL - Selection of the oldest order for every customer (join two tables)

Tags: sql, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following tables:

```
 - CUSTOMERS (ID_CUSTOMER, LASTNAME_CUSTOMER) 
 - ORDERS (ID_ORDER, DATE_ORDER, ID_CUSTOMER)
```

and I need SQL request to show the oldest order for each customer, can anyone advise me effective way how to do this?

I got stuck here:

```
SELECT customers.lastname_customer, orders.date_order
FROM customers
JOIN orders
ON customers.id_customer = orders.id_customer
WHERE orders.date_order IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY orders.date_order
```

Thanks!

EDIT
Thanks for answers guys, but the solutios not work properly on ORACLE 11g (In the result I still see all orders for each customer, not the only oldest)

Comment: Edit your question and add sample data, desired results, and any attempt you have made to solve this problem.

Comment: To get extra brownie points share us a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) of your problem

Answer (score 0):

To get the oldest order

```
SELECT LASTNAME_CUSTOMER,MIN(DATE_ORDER) FROM customers c
INNER JOIN orders o on o.ID_CUSTOMER= c.ID_CUSTOMER
GROUP BY o.ID_CUSTOMER,LASTNAME_CUSTOMER
```